# Not getting proper response in Pabbly Refund API

Tags: post, postman, response, fastapi

I want to integrate the refund API of Pabbly but when i'm calling it using postman
There is an **Error Response**

[image: 1]

I'm also providing the basic auth (email and password) of the current user with active product and checkout page. Below is the api docs of pabbly that i'm referring.
https://apidocs.pabbly.com/

Comment: The page you are linking to immediately states that authentication is through bearer token, not basic auth.

Comment: Thank you for the response @JarroVGIT but in the docs it is mentioned you will need the basic auth.
you could check it here [link] (https://apidocs.pabbly.com/#9292d8a6-78d2-419e-a653-e1e3bb937f69) in the payment refund

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the API uses Basic Auth as an authorization channel.

Username: API Key from your Pabbly Subscription Account

Password: Secret Key from your Pabbly Subscription Account

Location of API Key in Pabbly Subscriptions account -

From your accounts dashboard go to;

Settings -> API Settings -> Generate the Keys

Comment: Ohh.. Thanks.
I was giving the email & password for authorization.